# Apostrophe cms : widget html template check if image is set

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In Apostrophe CMS, how do you check if an image is set in the template?

For example, if I have a "title" field, 
`{% if data.widget.title %}` works fine.

However, with image, set like this:
`{{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'image', 'apostrophe-images', {}) }}`
The same pattern does not work as `data.widget.image` is always `[object][object]'`

I've done some reading and worked out that images are passed differently as they are part of `pieces` but cannot get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image field is dealing with only a single image:

```
{% set image = apos.images.first(data.widget.image) %}
{% if image %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

You can also use `apos.images.all` if you need some logic based on the number of images in the array:

```
{%- set images = apos.images.all(data.widget.slideshow) -%}
{% if (images.length > 1) %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

[There's an example of this logic in this bit of documentation as well.](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#creating-custom-templates-for-our-index-of-people)

Comment: (this is the answer, just not sure how to accept it etc).